# How to parse data from javascript to nodejs and then save in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I found this codepen register form which I really like.

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/arcs/pen/OmZaex)

I'm trying to parse data from javascript and I used `$.ajax` to POST data to Nodejs.

I get data in Nodejs I can console.log them. But when I'm trying to save these data to Mongodb but I get

> ERROR 500

Here is my register POST route.

```
router.post('/registracia', function(req, res, next) {
  var questions = req.body;
  var name = questions[0].answer;
  var surname = questions[1].answer;
  var email = questions[2].answer;
  var password = questions[3].answer;

  var newUser = {name: name, surname: surname, email: email, password: password};
  console.log(newUser);

  User.create(newUser, function(err, newlyCreated){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(newlyCreated);
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  })
});
```

Here is the ajax POST

```
var requestMedia = $.ajax({
    url: "/uzivatel/registracia",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(questions),
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lRav.png)

I appriciate any help. Thanks

Comment: And what is mongo complaining about? In the error I can only asume User is some sort of abstraction but Mongo should be complaining about something. Run your code using --inspect and set some breakpoints on Chrome or add more logs so you can see where is your problem. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: could you give the full node logs for the error?